# is there a way to input multiple content in multiple html tag element?

Tags: html, emmet

I just wonder is there a fastest way to input each of these character

所戸戻肩涙雇編偏啓房扇扉炉肇遍顧 in each one html element.

until now I did like this manually one by one

```
   <div class=place>所</div>
   <div class=door>戸</div>
   <div class=back>戻</div>
   <div class=shoulder>肩</div>
   <div class=tears>涙</div>
```

just wonder is there a easier and fastest way to input those character maybe in one or two line of code ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

With some JS you could create a [loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382450/dynamically-display-html-elements-via-loop), inputting each one of those characters with their specific class.

I don't know why you'd want to though? If you just do it once in the HTML, then that will be it done forever. Otherwise, it will always have to be done dynamically and only work on browsers that are allowing scripts.